# Select Word under mouse pointer in Qt

Tags: qt

I need to highlight and get the word under the mouse pointer when i press the right click in a QTextBrowser. I already implemented the **showContextMenu** function for the **QTextBrowser** for the right mouse click thing. However i can't highlight the word under the mouse pointer and extract it. I found the following solution online:

```
QTextCursor tc = txtBrwsr->textCursor();
tc.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
QString word = tc.selectedText();
```

However, it is not working and the **word** is empty, my aim behind this is to get the word and highlight it even if the user didn't highlight the word before pressing the right mouse click.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Use `txtBrwsr->setTextCursor(tc);` after `tc.select(...)`.
I tried your example, it's work for me (Qt 4.8.1, Mac).

Answer (score 4):

`textCursor()` function returns a copy of the QTextCursor.
You need call `setTextCursor()` after all changes.

That's example of how to highlight word under mouse cursor after right button click.

*MyTextBrowser.h*

```
class MyTextBrowser : public QTextBrowser {
// ...
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent);
// ...
};
```

*MyTextBrowser.cpp*

```
void MyTextBrowser::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *mouseEvent) {
    if (Qt::RightButton == mouseEvent->button()) {
        QTextCursor textCursor = cursorForPosition(mouseEvent->pos());
        textCursor.select(QTextCursor::WordUnderCursor);
        setTextCursor(textCursor);
        QString word = textCursor.selectedText();

        qDebug() << word;
    }
    QTextBrowser::mousePressEvent(mouseEvent);
}
```

Good luck.