# Creating mouse-over event listerners for Qt text fragments

Tags: javascript, c++, qt

Is it possible to create a mouse-over event listners on Qt text fragments, and how?

I.e., much like creating a JavaScript onMouseOver event on HTML span elements, can the same be done with Qt in C++? Please demonstrate with a solution that would change the background color of that text fragment/span itself.

For example, if you loaded this question's text into a text element, how can you ensure that only the words "you" are highlighted when mousing over them? In HTML, I would just put all "you"s into a span and add a JS event. Is this possible to do with (HTML) text loaded in a Qt application, too?

Comment: Probably, you need `QWidget::setMouseTracking(true)` and override virtual `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()`

Comment: If you really want to use some kind of 'event listeners', you can `emit` some custom `signal` from inside `QWidget::mouseMoveEvent()` and `connect` it to whichever `slot` you need.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But how to assign that to text spans/fragments inside a Text or TextEdit field? I assume this must have something to do with assigning listeners to a [QTextDocumentFragment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocumentfragment.html), [QTextFragment](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextfragment.html), or similar, right?

Comment: So far, it seems to me it is much easier to use QWebView and work with JavaScript and HTML5. That makes it a bit more difficult to edit the content, but at least adding this kind of highlighting functionality is much easier. So unless someone comes up with a working solution, I fear the answer to my question might be: **No, it is not possible, unless you use [QWebView](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwebview.html), JavaScript, and HTML5.**

Comment: You may want to look, for example, here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12545286/select-word-under-mouse-pointer-in-qt   After all, QTextDocument, QTextCursor, QSyntaxHighlighter are your friends.

Answer (score 0):

So according to tags, I can assume that you need qml [Mouse Area](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-mousearea.html)

And also by defaul signals(onEntered/onExited) is only emitted if a button is currently pressed. So you need set hoverEnabled to true to emit this signals even when no mouse button is pressed.

```
Text{
    id: text1;
    text: qsTr("SOME BIG TEXT")
    font.pixelSize: 24
    color: "black";
    MouseArea {
        id: area;
        anchors.fill: parent;
        hoverEnabled: true
        onEntered: {
            text1.color = "red";
        }
        onExited: {
            text1.color = "black";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: That is the direction; but it does not address text *fragments*. For example, if you loaded this comment's text into a text element, how can you ensure that only the words "you" are highlighted when mousing over them? In HTML, I would just put all "you"s into a span and add a JS event. Is this possible to do with (HTML) text loaded in a Qt application, too?